# tf.function uses all CPU RAM

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I cannot understand why the function I have posted below uses up all of my RAM. I could understand if I were running it eagerly, but I thought the point of a tf.function was to create a graph that is reused, much like creating an operation and running it in tf 1.x. I am new to tensorflow 2.0 so I might have the wrong idea about what tf.function is doing.

```
@tf.function
def clip_w(self, weight):
    return tf.clip_by_value(weight, -0.01, 0.01)
```

Could anyone help me understand this? Thanks

EDIT: Here is the code where I use this function

```
def clip_weights(self):
        for l in self.C.layers:
            weights = l.get_weights()
            weights = [self.clip_w(w) for w in weights]
            l.set_weights(weights)
```

Comment: **defining** the function shouldn't eat up memory. How are you calling it?

Comment: @Stewart_R I'm essentially calling it after every training step in another function. I thought the idea was that calling this function would just execute the graph and not create more and more nodes?

Comment: Is it possible that `weight` has a different shape each time? If so this could cause 'retracing' of the function and you could end up with a graph that's exploding in size eating up all the memory? Can we see this in context?

Comment: @Stewart_R Hm, I'm pretty certain `weight` is just shape (1,) every time. I've added the code where I use this code to my original post.

Comment: I take that back, I misread the keras documentation, l.get_weights() should return a list of numpy arrays, so I think it would make sense that they'd have different shapes.